# What should be an appropriate value for Kafka consumer concurrency (regard to scaling)?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm creating a new service which will be a consumer of Kafka topic. It's Spring app so I'm using spring-kafka.

Topic has 20 partitions. In the beginning, there are two instances in Kubernetes. In future, depends on load, we want to scale and run additional instances. What should be the appropriate value of `kafka.consumer.concurrency` in my case? I bet that 10, but am I right?

When there are only two service instances, each one runs 10 threads and each thread reads from one partition. But what if I would like to scale service? What will happen if I run two additional instances? As far as I know, when a new consumer joins a consumer group the set of consumers attempt to "rebalance" the load to assign partitions to each consumer.

1. Does it mean that two existing instances will reduce threads number to 5 and will listen on only 5 partitions (and each instance will handle 5 partitions)?
2. Is my understanding correct?
3. If not, what should be the appropriate value in my case?

Documentation says:

> if you have more partitions than you have threads, some threads will receive data from multiple partitions

4. Just to make sure: if I set concurrency to e.g. 5, each thread will read from two partitions. Will it affect service performance?

Answer (score 2):

When a new consumer is added to the same group, Kafka will perform a rebalance; if there are more consumers than partitions, there is no guarantee that each instance will get 5 partitions - Kafka just sees 40 consumers and the 20 partitions will be distributed. However, it probably depends on configured Assignor - the default `RangeAssignor` seems to do it that way.

However, when you exceed the number of partitions, the containers will have idle threads (assigned no partitions).

Generally, the best practice is to over-provision the number of partitions and let each consumer handle multiple partitions; that way, when you scale out; you won't end up with idle consumers.

> If not, what should be the appropriate value in my case?

It depends entirely on your application.

Bottom line; if you start with 2x10 consumers, and you expect you might end up requiring 10x10, you should start out with 100 partitions.